# Класс *.cpp, представляющий java.lang.Object в JVM

Tags: java, jvm, синхронизация

пытаюсь найти в исходниках JDK класс/файл с расширением `*.cpp`, который представляет джавовый объект (`java.lang.Object`) в виртуальной машине.

В нём меня интересует структура, ответственная за захват монитора при синхронизации на объекте.

Насколько я понимаю, синхронизация в Java возможна на любом объекте, т.е. эта структура обязательно присутствует его в заголовке.

Comment: Точки входа в то, что вы ищите, находятся [здесь](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l601).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо! Буду курить :)